# How would I use "the heck" or "on earth" to put emphasis on a "how much" question?

Tags: emphasis

I would like to add "on earth" or "the heck" to put emphasis on a "how much" question. What I mean by this is you can add emphasis to a "what" question like this, for example:

> What is a ...

can be changed to

> What the heck is a ...

I am just using ... as an example.

My question is how would I add a "the heck" to put emphasis on this question.

> How much does a ... cost?

In simplified terms

> What is a ...?

is to

> What the heck is a ...?

as

> How much does a ... cost?

is to what?

I googled "How the heck much" (quotes included), and this question was the first hit, so I don't quite understand the argument that this question shows lack of research effort.

Comment: *How the heck much does a house cost?* and equally *How on earth much does he earn?* are both idiomatic forms in an everyday spoken register in the UK.

Comment: @WS2 Again, I'd have said the opposite. There must be two UKs (at least). Have you already Brexited? //// Only 253 Google hits for "How the heck much does". / 7 for "How on earth much". // Google Ngrams flatline.

Comment: The usage is quite common ("Who the heck is that?" / "Where the heck is that spanner?" / "Why the heck did you sell my best coat?"" / "How the heck + modal or other aux + S + V(...)?" [esp 'should I know?'; 'are we going to get there?' etc], but with 'which', 'how much', 'how far' etc it is unavailable or uncommon. A less pleasant variant is sometimes used instead.

Comment: For "How the heck much" I got 4000 Google matches.  But of course this is a "polite" form of "how the hell much" with 221,000 or other still more profane versions.

Comment: You can say "What the heck does a thing cost?"

Comment: "How ***flipping*** much does that cost?" Which is similar to the AmEng *frigging* but, in my view, less abrasive sounding.

Comment: @Mari-LouA what is AmEng?

Comment: American English

Comment: @Mari-LouA Ok got it

Comment: Why did the answer get deleted